# R Sweave Computer Modern font usage

Tags: r, fonts, sweave

I've installed the R packages `extrafont` and `fontcm`. Then tried to plot the data with Computer Modern font in Sweave:

```
<<test,fig=TRUE,echo=False>>=
plot(na, family="CM Roman")
@
```

But it fails with error:

```
> grDevices::pdf.options(useDingbats = FALSE); utils::Sweave('test.Rnw', encoding='UTF-8')
Writing to file test.tex
Processing code chunks with options ...
 1 : echo keep.source term verbatim (test.Rnw:76)
 2 : keep.source term verbatim pdf  (label = test, test.Rnw:80)

Error:  chunk 2 (label = test) 
Error in axis(side = side, at = at, labels = labels, ...) : 
  invalid font type
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In axis(side = side, at = at, labels = labels, ...) :
  font family 'CM Roman' not found in PostScript font database
2: In axis(side = side, at = at, labels = labels, ...) :
  font family 'CM Roman' not found in PostScript font database
3: In axis(side = side, at = at, labels = labels, ...) :
  font family 'CM Roman' not found in PostScript font database
4: In axis(side = side, at = at, labels = labels, ...) :
  font family 'CM Roman' not found in PostScript font database
5: In axis(side = side, at = at, labels = labels, ...) :
  font family 'CM Roman' not found in PostScript font database
6: In axis(side = side, at = at, labels = labels, ...) :
  font family 'CM Roman' not found in PostScript font database
7: In axis(side = side, at = at, labels = labels, ...) :
  font family 'CM Roman' not found in PostScript font database
Error in rle(filenames) : 'x' must be an atomic vector
Calls: <Anonymous> -> <Anonymous> -> RweaveTryStop
Execution halted
```

`loadfonts(device="postscript")` shows that fonts is `already registered with postscriptFonts()`

How can I use it with Sweave?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Appears to be a stupid and easy question. I need to load `extrafont` and `fontcm` packages in my Sweave file:

```
<<setup,echo=FALSE>>=
    library(extrafont)
    library(fontcm)
@
```

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure you are using the right name? Try this and see if the results are informative:

```
> names(postscriptFonts() )
 [1] "serif"                "sans"                 "mono"                 "AvantGarde"          
 [5] "Bookman"              "Courier"              "Helvetica"            "Helvetica-Narrow"    
 [9] "NewCenturySchoolbook" "Palatino"             "Times"                "URWGothic"           
[13] "URWBookman"           "NimbusMon"            "NimbusSan"            "URWHelvetica"        
[17] "NimbusSanCond"        "CenturySch"           "URWPalladio"          "NimbusRom"           
[21] "URWTimes"             "ComputerModern"       "ComputerModernItalic" "Japan1"              
[25] "Japan1HeiMin"         "Japan1GothicBBB"      "Japan1Ryumin"         "Korea1"              
[29] "Korea1deb"            "CNS1"                 "GB1"
```

On review I see that pdf.options was involved and you may also need to examine:

```
 > names( pdfFonts() )
```